# Cannot sign app bundle with an existing key I use for signing APKs

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I want to update my app on Play Store with a new app bundle (previously I was uploading APKs). But when I try to generate signed app bundle with the key I was using for signing APKs, Android Studio gives me `jarsigner error` with the message *"Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"*. How can I generate a signed app bundle, so that I can upload it to the Play Console?

I performed Clean & Rebuild and tried again and again, but no luck. Then I thought maybe app bundles need a new key, and I successfully generated a signed app bundle with a new key I created. Tried to upload it, but predictably, Play Console gave me *"Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your app bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again"*. So what am I doing wrong?

Generating an app bundle with an existing key I was using for uploading APKs, gives me this error:

```
Cause: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was 
tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

With this stack trace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)  
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was 
tampered with, or password was incorrect
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300),
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
... 34 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was 
tampered with, or password was incorrect
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
at kotlin.io.CloseableKt.closeFinally(Closeable.kt:53)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.BundleTask.bundleModules(BundleTask.kt:128)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was 
tampered with, or password was incorrect
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.OpenJDKJarSigner.sign(OpenJDKJarSigner.kt:93) 
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.JarSigner$signer$1.invoke(JarSigner.kt:39)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.JarSigner$signer$1.invoke(JarSigner.kt:25)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.JarSigner.sign(JarSigner.kt:45)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.BundleTask$BundleToolRunnable.run(BundleTask.kt:204)
at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:39)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalInterruptibleAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:361)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1001)
... 55 more
```

How can I solve this issue, and what am I missing?

Comment: try signing an apk  to check password or any problem in your keystore. or open your keystore with http://keystore-explorer.org/ and check it

Comment: @beigirad I have tried to generate signed APK with the keystore, it works just fine. But with the same keystore, I cannot generate signed app bundle. I have checked the keystore with KeyStore Explorer and only difference I can see is that the alias is lowercase whereas I was entering CapitalizedWords, but since I can successfully generate a signed APK with it, it should not be the problem.

Comment: File a bug on Android Studio issue tracker.

Comment: @Pierre Yeah, apparently it's a grave bug. My password was containing non-ASCII characters. I suspected that might be the case, and created a new keystore with a password containing non-ASCII characters. When I try to generate a signed app bundle with that  newly created keystore with password containing special characters, I get this error.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is the following.

I had in my build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

and changed it to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
```

After that worked like a charm.

Comment: Same here. Weird bug. Thanks for posting this